# How to delete an object from an embedded nested array in mongodb using mongoTemplate?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, nosql, mongotemplate

I have following collection in MongoDB:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("64b7ad6338239f31795dba78"),
    "appId" : "APP-40047",
    "endpoints" : [
        {
            "originEndpointId" : "64b6c4cbf527e80a7f3c0496",
            "attributes" : [ "multiple_vehicles.vehicle.vin" ],
            "version" : "v1"
        },
        {
            "originEndpointId" : "64b6c8e29db5e76387614b9a",
            "attributes" : [ "multiple_vehicles.vehicle.vin" ],
            "version" : "v1"
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to perform a delete operation using mongoTemplate in my SpringBoot application.

I want to delete where **_id: "64b7ad6338239f31795dba78"** and **endpoints.originEndpointId = "64b6c8e29db5e76387614b9a"**

**Then the expected document look like:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("64b7ad6338239f31795dba78"),
    "appId" : "APP-40047",
    "endpoints" : [
      
        {
            "originEndpointId" : "64b6c8e29db5e76387614b9a",
            "attributes" : [ "multiple_vehicles.vehicle.vin" ],
            "version" : "v1"
        }
    ]
}
```

I got the expected result using mongoShell query:

```
db.tenantObjects.updateOne({ _id: ObjectId("64b7ad6338239f31795dba78")}, {
    $pull: {
        endpoints: { originEndpointId: "64b6c8e29db5e76387614b9a"}
    }
})
```

But I need this same thing using mongoTemplate. I am totally stuck in following mongoTemplate codes and also did not find good documentation yet.

```
  public void deleteTenantEndpoint(String tenantId, String endpointId, String collectionName) {
    log.debug("Trying to delete the endpoint with id {}, assigned to tenant {}", endpointId, tenantId);

    Query queryTenant = new Query();
    queryTenant.addCriteria(Criteria.where("_id").is(tenantId)
            .andOperator(Criteria.where("endpoints.originEndpointId").is(endpointId)));

    Query query = new Query();
    query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("endpoints.originEndpointId").is(endpointId));

    Update update = new Update();
    update.pull("endpoints.originEndpointId", query);

    UpdateResult deleteResult = mongoTemplate.updateFirst(queryTenant, update, collectionName);

    if (deleteResult.getMatchedCount() >= 1.0) {
      log.info("Successfully deleted the endpoint with id {}, assigned to tenant {}", endpointId, tenantId);
    } else {
      // TO_DO: Modify Error Handling
      log.error(TENANT_NOT_FOUND_MESSAGE, tenantId);
      throw new TenantObjectNotFoundException();
    }

  }
```